# Calculating hard disk fault tolerance on Software RAID 10

Tags: software-raid, mdadm

I have a machine with a level 10 software RAID (with mdadm).

I'd like to calculate the drive fault tolerance, but I have no idea how to do so.

Thanks for your attention

Comment: I should also point out it has a far layout with f=2

Answer (score 1):

With RAID 10 you are guaranteed to be able to survive a single disk failure. After that you are playing Russian roulette.

Basically R10 is a strip of mirrors. So you can lose a single disk in each mirror and be ok, once you lose both disks in a single underlying mirror the strip dies.

So the fault tolerance on a R10 array is 1, but you can lose UP TO 50% of your disks if you are a lucky person.

Comment: But in this case I'm using 7 disks, and I think software raid with mdadm is not exacly laid out as a regular 1+0 RAID

Comment: So you have 3 mirrors of two disks with a hot spare right? That doesn't change anything since you are still degraded while the HS is syncing and if you lose that second disk you are done. HS disks just give you quicker MTTR since there is normally no manual intervention.

Comment: No hot spare, its a software RAID, it accepts an odd number of disks because it's not laid out the same as hardware RAID 1+0

Comment: ... then ... it's not R10?

Comment: It's software RAID level 10, it shares the name, but it's not the same as a regular RAID 1+0

Comment: For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10